# Actualizar campo id de una base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Ejemplo:

tengo los siguientes registros:

```
(1,'campo','campo','campo'),
(40,'campo','campo','campo'),
(298,'campo','campo','campo'),
(1205,'campo','campo','campo'),
(15489,'campo','campo','campo');
```

pero quiero actualizar los ids para que queden:

```
(1,'campo','campo','campo'),
(2,'campo','campo','campo'),
(3,'campo','campo','campo'),
(4,'campo','campo','campo'),
(5,'campo','campo','campo');
```

imaginando que es una base de datos grande, que sentencia sql podria usar?

Comment: Es un primary key, pero no tiene auto_increment

Answer (score 4):

Usando variables de usuario:

```
UPDATE tabla
  JOIN (SELECT @id:=0) x
  SET id=(@id:=@id+1);
```

Opcionalmente, si después quieres el `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla DROP PRIMARY KEY, MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Como indicas en los comentarios, que solo tiene el atributo `PRIMARY KEY` debemos removerlo, pues primero pondremos todos los valores a 0

---

```
ALTER TABLE tablaNombre DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

2. Ahora actualizamos todos los valores a 0 actualizando esa columna de forma general

---

```
UPDATE tablaNombre SET id = 0;
```

3. Modificamos la columna `id` agregándole de nuevo el atributo `PRIMARY KEY` y agregando también `AUTO_INCREMENT` para que vaya sumando desde el 1 en adelante y ponga los valores que tu deseas; de modo que para los registros futuros que hagas se mantiene el incremento de `n + 1` por cada renglón

---

```
ALTER TABLE tablaNombre MODIFY COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

4. Si ahora hacemos un `SELECT` general a dicha tabla veras que ya sale en `id` los valores que indicas

Answer (score 0):

La solución trivial es con un procedimiento almacenado, pero igual también se podría hacer combinando un UPDATE con un JOIN, si se me ocurre cómo, te lo pongo a continuación.

De momento te paso el procedimiento para que salgas del paso:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE renumera()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE i,n,vid int;
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM castillo;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM castillo;
    set i=1;
    OPEN c1;
    WHILE i<=n DO 
      FETCH c1 INTO vid;
      UPDATE castillo set id=i WHERE id=vid;
      SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
  END;
```

Ya sabes, se llama con:

```
CALL renumera();
SELECT * FROM castillo;
```

Y verás este resultado:

> ```
> 1 campo   campo   campo
> 2 campo   campo   campo
> 3 campo   campo   campo
> 4 campo   campo   campo
> 5 campo   campo   campo
> ```

Aporto el dataset en SQL para facilitar las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE castillo(
  id int,
  campoA varchar(15),
  campoB varchar(15),
  campoC varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO castillo (id, campoA, campoB, campoC) VALUES
  (1,'campo','campo','campo'),
  (40,'campo','campo','campo'),
  (298,'campo','campo','campo'),
  (1205,'campo','campo','campo'),
  (15489,'campo','campo','campo');
```